# Median aggregation in tableau when connected to redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

We are using tableau and we are connected live to a redshift data source.
I cannot seem to find the Median aggregate function that i see when i connect to other types of data sources. Is this a known issue? We can't seem to find anything about it. Can we overcome it somehow using some kind of custom function?

Comment: SAP HANA also has this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'm not a Redshift expert. However I know in other cases when the underlying datastore doesn't offer Median (MySQL for example), then a direct Tableau connection can't find the median.

If you use a Tableau extract, "Median" should appear as an aggregation option. This is due to the fact that Tableau has a median in its own data store implmentation.

Comment: CountD is another example of an aggregation function that is only supported by some data connections. As with median, one workaround is to use a Tableau extract. Of course, that option might be unattractive for extremely large data.

Comment: Yes, it seems Redshift doesn't support Median